# Paragraph ended before \text@ was complete. <to be read again> \par

Tags: r, math, latex, equation

I'm knitting my R markdown file to pdf and keeps getting this error

```
\begin {align}
\text {using the relation} \\
point estimate \pm z^{2} * SE \\
\text {where z is the z statistic corresponding to 95% of Norm distribution} \\
\end {align*}
```

i think it's due to the use to `%` in line 4 of code. File knits when i remove that line or separate from code block.
pls how can i correct it in the code block. I have multiple scenarios like that in my Rmd

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339191/is-it-possible-to-write-the-symbol-in-text-in-latex

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
\text {where z is the z statistic corresponding to 95\(\%\) of Norm distribution} \\
```

That works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).